# Fetch data by time shifts - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, api

I am working on a shift based application where my workers work in 3 shifts, Morning 6am to 2pm, 2pm to 10pm and 10pm to 6am(next day).
I need to calculate to total time worked in each shifts which is logged in the database.

```
  $clientid = $_GET["clientid"];
  $date = $_GET["edate"];
  $shift = $_GET["shift"];

  if(!empty($clientid))
  {
    if($shift=='a')
    {
      $sq =  mysql_query("SELECT * from logusage WHERE etime BETWEEN '6:00:00' AND '14:00:00' AND clientid= '$clientid' AND edate = '$date'",$this->db);
    }
    else if($shift=='b')
    {
      $sq =  mysql_query("SELECT * from logusage WHERE etime BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '22:00:00' AND clientid= '$clientid' AND edate = '$date'",$this->db);
    }
    else if($shift=='c')
    {
      $sq =  mysql_query("SELECT * from logusage WHERE etime BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '6:00:00' AND clientid= '$clientid' AND edate= '$date'",$this->db);
    }
```

Whenever I try to access the Shift C, it fetches me data only till 11:59PM on that day as I am parsing the date too. How do I alter the sql to fetch data for the next day, till 6AM too?

Answer (score 1):

For the third one, you need to subtract hours to get the date correct:

```
SELECT * 
FROM logusage
WHERE etime BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '6:00:00' AND
      clientid= '$clientid' AND
      date(date_sub(edate, interval 6 hour)) = '$date';
```

Comment: This throws SQL Error, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Ive copy pasted your code in the third sql string.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to store EDATE and ETIME in a single column as TIMESTAMP value instead of 2 separate columns. It is also a good practice to store timestamps as GMT+00 values instead of your local time - but this only matters if your local time uses DST (day-light saving). Try the following code:

```
$clientid = (int)$_GET["clientid"];
$date = $_GET["edate"];
$shift = $_GET["shift"];

if($clientid != 0 AND $date != '')
{
    // I suppose $date is in format YYYY-MM-DD
    list($year,$month,$day) = preg_split('/-/',$date);
    switch($shift)
    {
        case 'a':
            $beg_stamp = mktime(6,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
            $end_stamp = $beg_stamp + 8*3600 - 1;
            break;
        case 'b':
            $beg_stamp = mktime(14,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
            $end_stamp = $beg_stamp + 8*3600 - 1;
            break;
        case 'c':
            $beg_stamp = mktime(22,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
            $end_stamp = $beg_stamp + 8*3600 - 1;
            break;
    }
    if($beg_stamp != '' AND $end_stamp != '') // not strictly needed, if $shift is always valid
        $sq = mysql_query('SELECT * from logusage WHERE clientid = '.$clientid.' AND TIMESTAMP(edate,etime) BETWEEN "'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$beg_stamp).'" AND "'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$end_stamp).'" ORDER BY edate,etime',$this->db);
}
```

You subtract 1 from the $end_stamp because the SQL predicate BETWEEN is inclusive - i.e. **x BETWEEN y AND z** is equivalent to **x >= y AND x <= z** and you do not want to catch work which belongs to the next shift.

Comment: We have deployed the migration to TIMESTAMP, however that will take some time as the entire system needs to be altered for the same.
In the meanwhile, the sql you have suggested has Y-m-d H:i:s, should I remove H:i:s from the .date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$beg_stamp)

Comment: No, you must not remove the H:i:s - you want to compare timestamp to timestamp, not timestamp to date. I suppose you are logging a work which has been started after the shift opening and finished before the shift closing. If you log a work which has been started by one shift but is so long that it could not be finished before the shift ends and is only finished by the next shift - it will be probably counted onto the first shift only.

Comment: This returns no output when I do have data that belongs to shift C on my database.

Comment: Can you show the actual query that is executed (after variables substitution) and the actual data from the table (3-5 records would be enough) so we can debug the issue ?

Comment: $sq = mysql_query('SELECT * from logusage WHERE clientid = '12342' AND TIMESTAMP(edate,etime) BETWEEN "'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$beg_stamp).'" AND "'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$end_stamp).'" ORDER BY edate,etime',$this->db);

Comment: `query =` SELECT work_type,worker_id,duration FROM logusage WHERE clientid=147 AND TIMESTAMP(edate,etime) BETWEEN "2016-08-01 22:00:00" AND "2016-08-02 06:00:00" ORDER BY edate,etime  `data =` row 1 (work_type, worker_id, edate, etime, duration) = 7, 9, 2016-08-01, 23:14:07, 00:40:24  row 2 (work_type, worker_id, edate, etime, duration) = 14, 3, 2016-08-01, 23:57:14, 03:27:04